# How can I add a parenthesis before the number 2500?

Tags: python

I'm trying to output the following two lines of text:

> The city with the most contracts is:
>
> Chicago (2500 contracts)

this is the code I'm using:

```
a = 'Chicago'
b = 2500
print('The city with the most contracts is:')
print(a, b, 'contracts)')
```

the current output is:

```
The city with the most contracts is:
Chicago 2500 contracts)
```

How can I add a parenthesis before the number 2500?

I tried adding the parenthesis as a string, as in:

```
print('The city with the most contracts is:')
print(a, '(', b, 'contracts)')
```

but it adds an unwanted space between the parenthesis and the number `2500`, looks like this:

```
The city with the most contracts is:
Chicago ( 2500 contracts)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is with a formatting string.

```
print(f'{a} ({b} contracts)')
```

Answer (score 2):

To handle manually the issue, you'd do

```
print(a, '(' + str(b), 'contracts)')
```

But you'd rather use the formatting solutions

```
print(f'{a} ({b} contracts)')

print('{} ({} contracts)'.format(a, b))

print('%s (%s contracts)' % (a, b))
```

Comment: Python prides itself on having one obvious right way to do things.  It's crazy that you were able to come up with 4 without any rationale on which is best.

Answer (score 1):

For Python 3.6+:

```
print(f"{a} ({b} contracts)")
```

For a prior version:

```py
print("{a} ({b} contracts)".format(a=a, b=b))
```

or

```py
print("{} ({} contracts)".format(a, b))
```

I will not encourage to format using `%`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using [string formatting](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp)

```
a = 'Chicago'
b = 2500

print("The city with the most contracts is:")
print("{} ({} contracts)".format(a,b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the plus sign instead of the comma.

```
a = "Chicago"
b = 2500
print(a + ' (' + str(b) + ' contracts)')
```

The output was:

```
Chicago (2500 contracts)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
a = 'Chicago'
b = 2500
print('The city with the most contracts is:')

print(a + ' (' + str(b) + ' contracts)')
```